# Iterate over html elements with same class using .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have some div elements with the same class. I want to iterate through them. I am using jquery ".each" in order to do it. I also want to access each element individually and toogle its class so I need to get the index of the element within the class elements array. I currently have a code similar to this:

```
 $('.the_div_class').each(function(i, obj) {

   if("a certain condition") {

    $('.the_div_class')[0].toggleClass('other_div_class'); // trying to access the index 0 of the array that contains the elements of that class;

   }

 }
```

However I receive an error saying "$(...)[0].toggleClass is not a function". If I don't specify an index I toogle all the elements of the array... I console.log the "$('.the_div_class')" array and get a structure similar to this:

```
[div.the_div_class, div.the_div_class, div.the_div_class, div.the_div_class, div.the_div_class, prevObject: r.fn.init[1]]
```

And if I console.log "$('.the_div_class')[0]" I get this:

```
<div class="the_div_class">
```

Why doesn't it work and what should I do in order to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code `$('.the_div_class')[0]` will only get the first element that matches that selector in the DOM with that class naively, it doesn't work because it's no longer a jQuery object (*hence it doesn't have the method `.toggleClass()`*). Inside `.each()` you can use `this` to refer to the current element being iterated:

```
 $('.the_div_class').each(function(i, obj) {

   if("a certain condition") {

    $(this).toggleClass('other_div_class'); 

   }

 }
```

---

*Note*: To get a item by it's index in jQuery you can use [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/). For example:

```
 $('.the_div_class').get(0).toggleClass('other_div_class');
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
var collection = $('.the_div_class');
collection.each(function(i, obj) {

   if("a certain condition") {
      $(collection[0]).toggleClass('other_div_class'); // trying to access the index 0 of the array that contains the elements of that class;
   }
}
```

You need to recreate jQuery object by passing DOM element to $ again, i.e $($('.the_div_class')[0]) for your code.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify the index, you're fetching the plain javascript element that was selected with jQuery, not a jQuery object.  This is why the toggleClass() method is unavailable to you.

You can wrap it in jQuery like this $($(selector)[i]) to convert it back to a jQuery object.  However, the arguments supplied with the each loop are your friend here.  That is, you can access the current object in the loop with $(obj).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the code to get element by using this keyword:

```
$('.the_div_class').each(function(i, obj) {
   if("a certain condition") {
    $(this).toggleClass('other_div_class'); // trying to access the index 0 of the array that contains the elements of that class;
   }
 }
```